# Is there a situation possible when breadth first search would not terminate?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, breadth-first-search

Does a situation exist when BFS would not terminate ?
(Given that the branching factor b is finite)

Comment: no - there isn't. unless you have a logical error in the code-- typically in keeping track of the already visited nodes maybe.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: did this just cross your mind, or did you implement a BFS that didn't do what it was supposed to?

Comment: So if we mark all the vertices that we have visited during the search we will always have a solution given that the graph is a finite graph and we have a goal defined for our search right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only BFS of an infinite graph and when the search doesn't have a specific, reachable target.  (You can certainly have an infinite graph with a finite branching factor.  An infinitely tall binary tree would suffice.)

The BFS algorithm by its definition looks at a vertex only once, and it looks at one vertex per iteration.  Therefore BFS of a graph with any finite number of vertices must terminate.

If the BFS has a reachable target T, then let P be a path from source to target.  If the branching factor is at most b, then after P^b steps the BFS must find T.

**Edit**

I think in retrospect I see the point of this question.  If the BFS is for a specific target node T on an infinitely large *directed* graph, then the BFS will fail to terminate if the search starts from a node from which T is inaccessible, even if the branching factor is limited.  For example, suppose you have any infinitely large DAG.  Then any node T that is a predecessor of the search start node is inaccessible, so the BFS will run forever without finding it.  NB this can't happen on a connected, *undirected* graph.

Comment: can see the point - however "infinite graph" is uncertain. BFS terminates at infinity whenever you can bring in an infinite graph.

Comment: @user3880721 That's a fairly silly statement. There is no such thing as "termination at infinity."  Termination is by definition halting in a finite number of steps of some abstract machine, often a Turing machine.  An infinite graph is a perfectly well-defined concept.  I gave an example: a tree with an infinite number of levels.  There are lots of algorithms that terminate on infinite graphs.  In fact if BFS is to find a specific target node, then BFS always terminates in finite time on an infinite graph!

Comment: @user3880721 I should have said infinite connected, _undirected_ graph above.  On a directed graph, the search can miss a specific unreachable target forever, so the algorithm never terminates.

Comment: What is a real-world example of infinite branching factor?

Answer (score 0):

No. For finite branching factors and a goal a finite number of steps away, BFS will always terminate.

It may take exponential time getting there, but it will get there in the end.

At step `n` of the algorithm, BFS will iterate every node that is `n` hops away. Therefore, any node that is a finite number `d` hops away is guaranteed to be found at step `d`.

If there are a finite number of nodes in each step up until step `d`, iteration of each step will terminate, and the node will be found.

Note that unlike DFS, BFS works fine on infinite graphs. It just doesn't work with infinite branching factors or with targets an infinite number of hops away.

Answer (score 0):

**No**. A well-implemented breadth-first search (BFS) algorithm will inevitably come to an end when applied to a finite graph. This assurance is achieved by keeping track of all visited vertices or edges in the graph and avoiding revisiting them. As the algorithm progresses, it enqueues unvisited nodes or edges while dequeuing those that have already been visited. Eventually, a moment will arise when there are no more unvisited elements left to enqueue, regardless of whether the desired target has been reached or not. At this juncture, the algorithm gracefully concludes its execution.